# How to handle acronyms in nltk synsets

Tags: python, nltk

Am trying to get synonyms of some words. Some are acronyms such as WHO(World Health Organization), or USA( United States of America) etc. Am trying to escape getting errors with the acronyms with this code:

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
def foo():    
    s = 'WHO'    
    ss = wn.synsets(s)[0]    
    print [str(x) if list in range in ss else s]
foo()
```

The problem is that I keep getting the error:

```
s = wn.synsets(ss)[0]
IndexError

: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am trying to escape getting errors with the acronyms

Problem is that it cannot find any synsets for `'WHO'`, so it returns an empty list, and your `[0]` results in an error as you can see.

Try avoiding it with this

```
def foo():    
    s = wn.synsets('WHO')
    if s:
        ss = s[0]
        print ss
```

Also, your list comprehension doesn't make sense, but that is not part of the problem.

Comment: Thanks. I though I could do the code with the list comprehension. Regards